# How to check your account's Google Apps Script quotas

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

Here is the link about the GAS quotas:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas

How can I check if I am getting close to certain quotas. For instance, how can I check, how many `UrlFetchApp` calls I have left for that day. Or how much Script time do I still left for that day.

I need to use this data to make decisions whether to run today or run tomorrow.

I need to check and verify quotas programatically only. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its not currently possible.
you need to tally those stats manually, maybe storing on script properties.

Comment: That really is bad.

Comment: Still not possible? You need to run a script to know your usage? That sounds nonlinear.

Comment: Any update on this?