# Monitor usage of Google Apps Script URLFetch

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using this http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json script to import JSON feeds for various APIs.

I've run into the problem of exceeding the daily limit, which is [20,000 URLFetch calls + 100MB / day](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

I'm not much of a programmer and have two questions:

1. At what point does the API call happen and count towards that daily limit? If I paste the script's formula into 100 cells, will it instantly make 100 calls?
2. Is there a way to monitor my usage? In terms of calls and data received?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly where you are using the calls I am just going to use one Google Sheet as an example:

1. When you open the spreadsheet / reload the spreadsheet it will call the data to update it, this means if you have 100 cells with the same function to call JSON then yes that will be 100 calls to the URL. That being said if you reload this 10 times in a day then that will only be 1,000 calls.
2. You could monitor this but you would possibly need to understand how the script editor works and make a small script.

If you have more information I can give you a more in depth answer with some solutions.

Hope that makes some sense of it all! :)

Comment: 1. that makes sense. I had a lot of cells with various versions of the script to call JSON and was reloading a lot, so I could see myself hitting 20,000 in a day. - my plan is to reduce the number of instances of the script and to make sure i'm careful about loading the spreadsheet

2. i'd love to be able to keep an eye on my usage. i've got a decent understanding of how the script editor works. i was able to install that script and modify parts of it.  so if you have thoughts on how i could add something in to monitor the usage, that'd be great. 

thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding on the question how to be able to keep an eye on your usage, It is not documented or you can not find any ideas on how to check it on the Google AppsScript documentation. By searching the internet, I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775124/how-to-check-your-accounts-google-apps-script-quotas) related to your problem. And the answer here it is not currently possible to check or monitor your usage, the workaround is you need to tally those stats manually, or maybe storing on script properties. For more info, check this [link](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/05/apps-script-dashboard-and-quotas.html).